# Google Cloud Cluster Container

Tags: google-app-engine, virtual-machine, containers, cluster-computing, google-kubernetes-engine

I have created a Google Cloud Cluster with 3 nodes. I'm not able to stop the vm instances at all? They just come back online. I've also tried to ssh in and sudo poweroff and still nothing. The vm instances will not turn off, which is a bit frustrating as they charge hourly as the instances are online. Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Cloud Cluster will keep your cluster alive. Until you delete cluster.

To delete cluster use following command:

```
gcloud container clusters delete my-cluster-id
```

Where `my-cluster-id` is your cluster. To get id use `gcloud container clusters list`.

See other cluster commands here: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/ (hint, you can resize it also, add/remove nodes, etc)

Comment: I had a feeling this was the case but I wasn't able to find any documentation to confirm this. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: yeah, it's how it designed. if you don't need it, it's better to use plain manually managed Cloud Instances

Answer (score 0):

To add onto Igor's great answer, if you'd like to change the size of your cluster without fully deleting it, you can run `gcloud container clusters resize NAME --size SIZE` to change your cluster to have SIZE nodes in it.

Comment: Thanks, that's nice to know!